# Class variables and extending a module

Tags: ruby, class-variables

I have a module like the following

```
module MyModule
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def foo
      @@var = 1
    end

    def bar
      puts @@var
    end
  end
end

class A
  include MyModule
  foo
end

class B < A; end
```

so that

```
 B.bar outputs '1'.
```

However, I would like to have .bar only be defined if .foo is called. I tried

```
module MyModule
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def foo
      @@var = 1
      extend SingletonMethods
    end

  module SingletonMethods
    def bar
      puts @@var
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that

```
B.bar
```

returns the error "uninitialized class variable @@var in MyModule::SingletonMethods".  How can I make it so that a variable defined in .foo is available to .bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [mattr_accessor](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.0.0/Module/mattr_accessor) instead

Comment: Is mattr_accessor Rails only?

Comment: Yes, but the implementation is pretty straightforward - https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/attribute_accessors.rb

Comment: this saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access class variables from a module using the self syntax

```
class User
  include Base
  @@attributes = [:slug, :email, :crypted_password]
end

module Base
  def self.included(base)
  base.extend ClassMethods
end

def headers
  if defined? self.attributes
    self.attributes
  end
 end
end
```

Now calling `User.headers` gives me the expected result of 
`[:slug, :email, :crypted_password]`

If anyone can shed more light on why this works exactly so in ruby, please let me know!